# Modifying & Relaying Mail

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

Is there any way to simply relay mails received by a PHP script? Instead of being received normally into a mailbox, I have routed all incoming mails to a PHP script that would parse and log them (from, subject, message text) into a text file.

This is the ***truncated*** version of the script:.

```
    <?php

        $feed = fopen ("php://stdin", 'r');
        $email = '';
        while (!feof($feed))
        {
            $email .= fread($feed, 1024);
        }
        fclose($feed);

        $to = explode...
        $from = explode..
        $subject = explode...
        $message = utf8_encode...

        $log = fopen("/home/.../log.txt", "a+");
        fwrite($log,...);
        fclose($log);   

    ?>
```

Would it be possible ***to relay the entire message, as is, to another recipient, but not as a forward***?

TIA.

Comment: I'd suggest doing this in your mail server config, not in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the email is received with a whole bunch of additional headers, from the original sender. So, it must be parsed, and only the required headers extracted and used. The relevant header entries could also be modified to change the sender & recipient information, as well as the subject. Once all that is done, the PHP mail() function could be used to re-send the email.

Simple, and it works. The only drawback is that GMail keeps reporting that the sender cannot be confirmed as the actual sender (or spammer).